# Python - return multiple values using tuple (AWS lambda function)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

This is the current code that I have:

```
def handler():
    ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="ap-southeast-2")
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name':'iam-instance-profile.arn', 'Values': ['arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/TestRole']}])
    for instance in instances:
        return (instance.private_ip_address)
```

I'm trying to return all the private_ip_addresses. This code only returns me 1 ip address but I should be getting back 3 addresses. If i did a `print` instead, it returns the correct 3 values

I did some research and found using **tuple** is a good way but it hasn't been working for me thus far. Here is an example code I'm trying out with tuple (that should work with my code if it is correct)

```
myList=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

def handler():
   tup=()
   for element in myList:
       tup+= (element,)
   return tup
```

This currently returns a null value. However, if i do  `print tup` , it returns me with `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong with my use of tuple. OR if there is a better way to do this (corresponding with how lambda functions work)?

Comment: It's a bad practice to modify a `tuple`, `list` and `set` are made for that purpose !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "`return (instance.private_ip_address)`" returns a tuple consisting of a single value. The fact that it is called from a loop, doesn't make any difference - as soon as the `return` statement is executed during the first iteration, the loop terminates.

The following should work:

```
def handler():
    ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="ap-southeast-2")
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name':'iam-instance-profile.arn', 'Values': ['arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/TestRole']}])
    return tuple([instance.private_ip_address for instance in instances])
```

Comment: No, `(instance.private_ip_address)` is not a tuple. `(instance.private_ip_address,)` or `instance.private_ip_address,` would be.

Answer (score 0):

In your handler code, when you use a `print` instead of a `return` it works fine as it doesn't break the loop or the function. But when Python encounters a return, it returns the value that we've asked it to return and concludes that the function end has been reached. It doesn't continue the loop and return a value again and again.

In order to correct your code, use any data structure in python that could hold multiple values such as a tuple or a list and append any value you need to return to that within the loop and once the loop is complete, return the data structure.